# Modify existing code to insert geom_count into a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I found this cool code sample with a great plot at the end. Unfortunately, does it not look too good if there are too many observations. So I tried to format the dots for each observations with `geom_count` and make them more compact. 
But simply adding `+ geom_count` does not do the trick. I get the error message:

> Error: stat_sum requires the following missing aesthetics: y

How to modify the `ggplot` to merge the dots?

Link to the original code: https://osf.io/bc3jz/

Link to the data: https://osf.io/ftnb2/download

```
    master = read.csv("binary log.csv")

model = glm(WORKSTAT ~ CHILDREN + RACE + CONTROL +
              ATTMAR + ATTROLE + SEL + ATTHOUSE +
              AGE + EDUC,
       family = binomial(link = 'logit'),
       data = master)

correct = model$fitted.values

##a cool dot plot
library(ggplot2)
theme = theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
              panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
              panel.background = element_blank(),
              axis.text.y=element_blank(),
              axis.ticks=element_blank(),
              axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black"),
              axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black"),
              text = element_text(size=20), 
              legend.key = element_blank())

hist = ggplot(master, aes(correct, color = WORKSTAT, fill = WORKSTAT))
hist +
  theme +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = .01, position = "jitter") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,1)) +
  xlab("All Predictors in Model") +
  ylab("Frequency") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Maroon", "#2C3539"),
                     labels = c("Not Working", "Working"),
                     name = "Working Category")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Maroon", "#2C3539"),
                    labels = c("Not Working", "Working"),
                    name = "Working Category") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=c(.50), linetype="dotdash", size = 1)
```

Edit:
The issue is, that I have too many observations to display them properly.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is `geom_histogram` what you are looking for?
E.g. like this:

`geom_histogram(position = "identity", alpha = .6)`

Replacing your `geom_dotplot` with this does result in the histogram "floating" above the x-axis, though. Which you can fix by adding `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))`

Comment: Thank you for comment but that doesn't solve the issue. The columns from the histogram are still way too large to display them properly

Comment: How do you display/save the plot? When I ran the code and saved the .png, it all looked fine. [Link to the image](http://i64.tinypic.com/29cwtg.png)
You need to increase the size bit before saving, though.

Comment: I see that you used a different data for the code vs. the plot that you have added. I don't know what the issue with that different data set is exactly, but you might just want to change the bin size of the y-axis.